# Tensorflow federated (TFF) 0.19 performs significantly worse than TFF 0.17 when running "Building Your Own Federated Learning Algorithm" tutorial

Tags: tensorflow-federated

At the very end the "*Building Your Own Federated Learning Algorithm*" tutorial it is stated ,after training our model for 15 rounds, we shall expect a `sparse_categorical_accuracy` around 0.25, but running the tutorial in colab as is gives a result between 0.09 and 0.11 based on my runs. Yet simply changing the tf and tff versions to 2.3.x and 0.17, respectively, gives a result around 0.25, just like we expected!

To replicate run the said tutorial as is, it should use tf 2.5 and tff 0.19. After that run the same tutorial by simply changing

```
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated
```

to

```
!pip install --quiet tensorflow==2.3.0
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated==0.17.0
```

Also tf 2.4 and tff 0.18 combination works just fine and gives a score around 0.25. So it is only tf 2.5 and tff 0.19 combination that doesnt give the expected result.

Just to be clear I am not saying first setup doesnt train the model; running it for 200 rounds shows a steady improvement in score reaching something like 0.7-0.8. I would appreciate a clarification on why thats the case, or if I made something wrong please point it out.

**Edit:** To make sure same clients were being used across different tff versions I have used the following codes

for training data

```
sorted_client_ids = sorted(emnist_train.client_ids)
sorted_client_ids2 = sorted_client_ids[0:10]

federated_train_data = [preprocess(emnist_train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x))
                       for x in sorted_client_ids2]
```

for test data

```
sorted_client_ids = sorted(emnist_test.client_ids)
sorted_client_ids2 = sorted_client_ids[0:100]

def data(client, source=emnist_test):
    return preprocess(source.create_tf_dataset_for_client(client))

central_emnist_test = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    [data(client) for client in sorted_client_ids2])).flat_map(lambda x: x)
```

I trained each for 50 rounds. The results I got with these settings are

for tff 0.17: loss: 1.8676 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5115

for tff 0.18: loss: 1.8503 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5160

for tff 0.19: loss: 2.2007 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1014

So my problem here is all three versions of tff had used same training data, same test data, the models had the same initialization and same rounds of training but the results for tff 0.19 and tff 0.18/0.17 was vastly different, whereas tff 0.18 and 0.17 had produced quite similar results.

Again just to clarify tff 0.19 had improved its accuracy as well, but to a significantly lesser degree.

**EDIT 2:** Following the advice of Zachary Charles I have used federated sgd. For tff 0.18 and 0.17 edit the first line.

```
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

import collections
import attr
import functools
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff

np.random.seed(0)

print(tf.__version__)
print(tff.__version__)

emnist_train, emnist_test = tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data()

NUM_CLIENTS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 20

def preprocess(dataset):
    def batch_format_fn(element):
        return(tf.reshape(element['pixels'],[-1,784]),
              tf.reshape(element['label'],[-1,1]))
    return dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).map(batch_format_fn)

sorted_client_ids = sorted(emnist_train.client_ids)
sorted_client_ids2 = sorted_client_ids[0:10]

federated_train_data = [preprocess(emnist_train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x))
                       for x in sorted_client_ids2]

def create_keras_model():
    return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(784,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, kernel_initializer='zeros'),
        tf.keras.layers.Softmax(),
    ])

def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_keras_model()
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
        keras_model,
        input_spec=federated_train_data[0].element_spec,
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
    
sorted_client_ids = sorted(emnist_test.client_ids)
sorted_client_ids2 = sorted_client_ids[0:10]

def data(client, source=emnist_test):
    return preprocess(source.create_tf_dataset_for_client(client))

central_emnist_test = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    [data(client) for client in sorted_client_ids2])).flat_map(lambda x: x)

def evaluate(server_state):
    keras_model = create_keras_model()
    keras_model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]  
    )
    keras_model.set_weights(server_state)
    keras_model.evaluate(central_emnist_test)


iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_sgd_process(
    model_fn,
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01))

state = iterative_process.initialize()
evaluate(state.model.trainable)

for round in range(50):
    print(round)
    state,_ = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)

evaluate(state.model.trainable)
```

The results I got are

Before training

- tff 0.19: loss: 2.3026 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1207
- tff 0.18: loss: 2.3026 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1010
- tff 0.17: loss: 2.3026 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1207

After training

- tff 0.19: loss: 2.2122 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1983
- tff 0.18: loss: 2.2158 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1700
- tff 0.17: loss: 2.2122 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFF 0.19 moved the provided datasets (including EMNIST, which is used in the tutorial) away from an HDF5-backed implementation to a SQL-backed implementation ([commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/commit/7bb20162f96e3d5bc28ce50b206de0138d9894eb#diff-b972dbb5d89109f52620511c6b3001706076a2031c6b27ea9b846e2431593cc7)). It's possible that this changed the ordering of the clients, which would change which clients are used for training in the tutorial.

It's worth noting that in most simulations, this should not change anything. Clients should generally be randomly sampled at each round (which is not done in the tutorial for reasons of exposition) and generally at least 100 rounds should be done (as you say).

I'll update the tutorial to guarantee reproducibility by sorting the client ids, and then selecting them in order.

For anyone who's interested, a better practice would be to a) sorting the client ids, and then b) sample using something like `np.random.RandomState`, as in the following snippet:

```
emnist_train, _ = tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data()
random_state = np.random.RandomState(seed=1729)
sorted_client_ids = sorted(emnist_train.client_ids)
sampled_client_ids = random_state.choice(sorted_client_ids, size=NUM_CLIENTS)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Initially I thought it made sense so I approved it, but after using the same clients across different tff versions I still got a huge difference between tff 0.19 and tff 0.18/0.17. You can see the full results and codes I have used for choosing clients in the edited section of my question. What you said makes perfect sense but I dont think it is the cause of the problem here. So I would appreciate if you can give a second look

Comment: One thing that may have changed between versions is the order of examples in each client's dataset, which would change the training dynamics. One test you could do (that would be greatly appreciated) would be to use [federated SGD](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/build_federated_sgd_process) in the different TFF versions and see if things still differ.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You can check my second edit for the code I have used. It is quite similar to tutorial codes you have provided. Following the results I have provided do you agree with my conclusion that "tff 0.17 and 0.19 had the same datasets with different order, whereas tff 0.18 had simply a different dataset, maybe a bit larger maybe a bit smaller"? Your comment on that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure why TFF v0.18 has different post-training values. The datasets themselves have not changed between versions, save for the order of clients and examples. It seems important that TFF v0.18 gave a different accuracy at initialization, so this may have been due to underlying changes in TF (eg. how metrics are computed), or it could simply be floating-point issues, it's tough to say.